# Does using pacman on MSYS2 install to my hard drive on Windows?

Tags: package, msys2, msys

Maybe this is a dumb question, but before I download a large package I want to make sure it works for what I need and I wasn't able to find this info. If anyone has experience using this software it would really help me out.

Specifically I want to know if `pacman -S some-package` will install on the system or will just be usable in msys2.

Comment: Of course it installs "to hard drive". Specifically, to the MSYS2 installation directory (normally `C:\msys64`). You can later delete the package (using `pacman -R`) to free the space, or delete the whole MSYS2 directory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat with that noted, if I install a package through MSYS2 not only does it stay on the hard drive but is it usable outside of the MSYS2 terminal? I guess the idea that the packages would normally be for Linux distros made me question it. If it does just integrate with Windows I'd be very pleased.

Comment: Being "inside of MSYS2 terminal" is not really special. The installed programs are just `.exe`s, which can be run from anywhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you, this gives me peace of mind. I tend to overthink these things.